# TFSAPI: Get previous version of a particular file

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk, changeset

I have a program which can retrieve the files associated with a particular changeset. I need to compare this file to its previous version. I need to download the previous version of the file for this. Can someone help out with this?
Specific documentation/links are also appreciated.

Comment: It is definitely helpful, but I can't find an equivalent in the .NET Client libraries.

Comment: You can refer to [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet) and [TfvcHttpClientBase.GetChangesetChangesAsync(Nullable<Int32>, Nullable<Int32>, Nullable<Int32>, Object, CancellationToken) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclientbase.getchangesetchangesasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to use the API call successfully.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I have added API calls to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to these API calls :

- [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet)
- [TfvcHttpClientBase.GetChangesetChangesAsync(Nullable,
  Nullable, Nullable, Object, CancellationToken)
  Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.sourcecontrol.webapi.tfvchttpclientbase.getchangesetchangesasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet)

You can compare two different versions of a file in Repos Files:

[image]

Then click in **History** to select a previous version:

[image]

As shown below, download the previous version of the file.

[image]

If you want to download files with rest api , you can refer to [Items - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0#examples) .

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&scopePath={scopePath}&recursionLevel={recursionLevel}&includeContentMetadata={includeContentMetadata}&latestProcessedChange={latestProcessedChange}&download={download}&$format={$format}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions={versionDescriptor.versionOptions}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&versionDescriptor.versionType={versionDescriptor.versionType}&includeContent={includeContent}&resolveLfs={resolveLfs}&api-version=5.0
```